# How to remove kernel installed using dpkg command?

Tags: 12.04, kernel, dpkg

I am using i386 architecture of Ubuntu 12.04,I downloaded latest kernel 3.12.7 from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12.7-trusty/ & installed it using dpkg -i.
Installation was all good, but after 40-50 minutes it freezes.
So, I would like to revert changes. How to uninstall the latest kernel 3.12.7 which I downloaded using dpkg command ?

Here's my `dpkg -l | grep "linux-[a-z]*-"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use apt or your favorite package manager to search and uninstall the packages.

```
apt-get remove packagename
```

Or use Software Center or Synaptic package manager and search for linux 3.12

Comment: That was simple, thanks!
I have to run sudo update-grub though :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `sudo apt-get --auto-remove purge linux-generic*3.12*`. Please note that, although wildcards tend to work will with apt-get, they don't work too well with dpkg directly (at least, not as far as I can tell).